# How to create virtualenv on flash disk

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

How to? I have an error:

```
wolf@wolf-pc:/media/C47D-5F53$ sudo virtualenv django
New python executable in django/bin/python
ERROR: The executable django/bin/python could not be run: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: What filesystem is on this drive?

Comment: Depending on your system, it's possible that the drive has been mounted with the `noexec` flag which means that the OS is prohibited from running apps under that mount.

Comment: How i can check it? i use ubuntu 12.04 and i'm not changed mounting settings

Comment: @LiGhT_WoLF Check mount options by running `mount`.  At the end of each line are the mount options in parenthesis.  Check to see if `noexec` is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same problem. I tried creating a virtualenv in my home folder and that worked fine, but I got that error when I tried to create one on a different partition.

So to fix your problem either try a different location or take a look at how stuff is mounted.

This will help if you take the latter approach:

[strange permissions problems for virtualenv python executable (lubuntu-12.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759549/strange-permissions-problems-for-virtualenv-python-executable-lubuntu-12-10)

Steve K might also be correct, I dont know... Virtualenv does work on windows. Please share how you ended up solving the problem if you have already done so

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need sudo to create a virtualenv. Maybe that's causing the problems?

Answer (score 0):

FAT32 does not handle these types of permissions, your key should be [reformatted with ext3](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2010/02/17/).

Comment: Is there are options? I may use this drive with windows, but win don't unserstand ext3