# virtualenv with VMWare(ubuntu) with mounted USB drive fails with Permission denied to exec python

Tags: python, virtualenv

When I run

```
virtualenv venv
```

it copies venv/bin/python but it has permission 600.
I am running ubuntu on VMWARE player.  The install of virtualenv went well. 
umask is set to 0002

Any tips on what to check?

**More info 2015.09.02**

Refer to fstab issue link below.

The issue has too do with VMWARE and support for USB connected drive, the mount needs to have certain options, esp. 'exec'.

**fstab issue reference**

I have looked issue of /etc/fstab issue ([strange permissions problems for virtualenv python executable (lubuntu-12.10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759549/strange-permissions-problems-for-virtualenv-python-executable-lubuntu-12-10)). I do not see mounted drive in the fstab file??

```
me@ubuntu:~$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sr0 on /media/me/OFFICE14 type udf (ro,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,umask=0077,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/me/Elements type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

me@ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=4b63de0e-4116-4271-acc8-0283944e2c86 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a7cc5d53-5882-4839-b460-545e582eee92 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

**Simple cp example**

When I try to "cp /usr/bin/python2.7" to mounted drive I see same issue of exec permissions and other permissions being altered.  I see the same issue... so something deep in mounting of Windows drive.

```
 me@ubuntu:~/w$ mkdir tmp
 me@ubuntu:~/w$ cp /usr/bin/python2.7 tmp
 me@ubuntu:~/w$ ls -l tmp/*
 -rw------- 1 rojasfr rojasfr 3345416 Sep  3 03:03 tmp/python2.7
 me@ubuntu:~/w$ cp /usr/bin/python2.7 /tmp
 me@ubuntu:~/w$ ls -l /tmp/py*
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 rojasfr rojasfr 3345416 Sep  3 03:03 /tmp/python2.7
```

*** virtualenv example ***
It works when virtualenv is run on root filesystem but not mounted ($HOME/w)  filesystem.

```
me@ubuntu:~$ mkdir /tmp/dev
me@ubuntu:~$ (cd /tmp/dev ; virtualenv venv)
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

me@ubuntu:~$ mkdir w/devtest
me@ubuntu:~$ (cd w/devtest ; virtualenv venv)
New python executable in venv/bin/python
ERROR: The executable venv/bin/python could not be run: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Here is install cmds:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Below is permisison of /usr/bin/py*

```
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Aug 20 00:36 python -> python2.7
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Aug 20 00:36 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3345416 Jun 22 11:51 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Aug 20 00:36 python3 -> python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4061272 Jun 19 08:35 python3.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4061272 Jun 19 08:35 python3.4m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Aug 20 00:36 python3m -> python3.4m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     231 Jun 19 08:34 pyvenv-3.4
```

Comment: Where did it copy the python from? Does that file have the correct perms?

Comment: Far as I can tell, python 2.7, and 3.4 came with ubuntu installed.

Comment: I thought this was solved by changing ownership of files on mounted drive.   But this did not fix the problem.

Comment: @sureshw: I added the permission of /usr/bin:

Comment: @frank6591... can you try with -p option of virtualenv?

Comment: I have tried the -p option on virtualenv.   I have simplified the issue to be a cp issue. see post above.

Comment: See this http://askubuntu.com/questions/23108/trying-to-make-file-executable-on-usb-but-the-permission-doesnt-stick

Comment: Thanks! Still not working even after I tried 
mount -o remount,exec /media/me/Elements
Not sure how to set /etc/fstab... investigating.

Comment: Ok. finally fixed it by changing /etc/fstab to have entry:
/dev/sdb1       /media/mountpoint  auto    auto,user,exec,nodev,rw  0       0